# <router-outlet> and <div ng-view>, AngularJS and Angular routing at the same time

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-routing, ng-upgrade

My app component (an Angular 2 component, downgraded for index.html) contains this:

```
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <div ng-view></div>
```

This is just like it says to do in "Dividing routes between Angular and AngularJS"
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#adding-the-angular-router-and-bootstrap

But the ng-view isn't picking up any AngularJS routes.

How would `ng-view` work in an Angular 2 template anyway? How am I supposed to be able to use both types of routers at the same time?

`<router-outlet></router-outlet>` isn't working either -- this html just shows up on the page statically as-is.

I have `<base href="/">` and the javascript console has no errors in it.

Google, message me :) who/ajxtaylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has gotten me closer in the right direction but it's still not working.

`<router-outlet>` wasn't working because I was missing the top level app component in the bootstrap array:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html#!#dividing-routes-between-angular-and-angularjs

Submitted GitHub issue regarding lack of error message: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14572

I don't know if the Angular AppComponent is supposed to have downgradeComponent called on it and if so, whether the index.html should use the AngularJS selector or the Angular selector.